# Advice on WYSIWYG architecture for an Ember app

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm having a hard time coming up with a solution for this problem.

I'm building a WYSIWYG designer, for micro sites. The templates for these microsites will be supplied by an intermediate user, and the end-user will manipulate these templates. So, there are really two groups of users of the app: template-buiders, and end-users. Think MailChimp.

This means my Ember app will start off with a template from a template-builder, say

```
<h1>An awesome product</h1>
<h2 contenteditable="true">Subtitle away</h2>
<p>{{#if optionA}} One thing {{else}} Another thing {{/if}}<p>
```

and the end user, having chosen this template, will then be able to customize it. There are a few requirements:

- There will be static, uneditable portions of the page (`h1` above)
- There will be static, editable portions of the page (`h2` above)
- There will be options that affect the layout, style, etc. (`p` above)

So far, my attempts have lead me to build a handlebars helper that takes a string and a context, and returns a rendered template. This is because the above template will actually be coming over from a database, as a string - remember, it's user-generated.

That means, in my *application's* template, it would look like

```
<div class="preview">
  {{preview-userTemplate template context}}}
</div>
```

where

```
template: '<h1>An awesome product</h1><h2 contenteditable="true">Subtitle away</h2><p>{{#if optionA}} One thing {{else}} Another thing {{/if}}<p>',
context: {optionA: true}
```

Now, this actually works, in the sense that it will update if `context` is updated, so I can add controls along the sides for the *end-user* to manipulate those options. So I have those (more of less) under control.

It's the WYSIWYG content editing that is giving me trouble. In the above template (from my template-builder users), I want them to be able to add `contenteditable="true"` to places in their templates where the end-users can change the content.

Now, these changes need to be saved. Ideally, I would be able to retrieve the *instance view's template back from the DOM*, after the inline edits have been made. Is this possible? The original `{{data}}` placeholder would need to be preserved.

Alternatively, I could make a view/component, so the template-builder would do something like this:

```
<h1>An awesome product</h1>
{{#editable}}
  <h2>Subtitle away</h2>
{{/editable}}
<p>{{#if optionA}} One thing {{else}} Another thing {{/if}}<p>
```

but this seems like it would require a good deal of finagling to get the edits to stick - I'm not even sure right now how I'd go about it.

What do you guys think? Is there an easier solution that I'm overlooking? Thanks for any pointers!